# Python: How to get minutes of time (e.g. night of workdays, weekends, holidays) between two datetimes?

Tags: python, date, datetime, time

```
import datetime as dt

night_hours = [18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
holidays = ["2023-04-01", "2023-04-05", "2023-04-11"]

dt_fmt = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"
start_dt = dt.strptime("2023-04-01 12:00", dt_fmt)
end_dt = dt.strptime("2023-04-15 23:00", dt_fmt)

minutes_of_all_workday_nights = ???
minutes_of_all_the_weekends = ???
minutes_of_all_the_holidays = ???
```

How can I get the values of the last three variables in Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple loop from start date to end date with a step of 1 min and 3 different counters should do the trick for you. Check this out:

```py
current_dt = start_dt
while current_dt <= end_dt:
    if current_dt.weekday() < 5 and current_dt.hour in night_hours:
        minutes_of_all_workday_nights += 1
    
    if current_dt.weekday() >= 5:
        minutes_of_all_the_weekends += 1
    
    if current_dt.date().isoformat() in holidays:
        minutes_of_all_the_holidays += 1
    
    current_dt += dt.timedelta(minutes=1)

print(minutes_of_all_workday_nights)
print(minutes_of_all_the_weekends)
print(minutes_of_all_the_holidays)
```